# Resource images (icons and renderer window images) are missing in installed electron app

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Once electron app is installed into system and opened. Icons and images do not appear. Seems like i am missing some configuration settings. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using electron-builder? What's in your build package.json? Where are the files of your app that should get packaged?

Comment: @NoxNoctis I am using electron-build for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes that i made,

1. I figured out, i was excluding assets folder (specifically icons) in files section of electron-builder configuration. So including significant files made it appeared.

[image]

2. updated the base uri for images.

```
<base href="./">
```